# swig char ** as a pointer to a char *

Tags: python, c++, pointers, swig

I'm having trouble with swig and char ** as pointer to a variable char * (not as a list of char *!!!). I couldn't find out a way to wrap the pointer to a char *.

The aim is to write the result of the concatenation in the char * referenced by the pointer.

The following is my code:

File pointers.cpp:

```
#include "pointers.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res){
  char *aux = (char *)malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1);
  strcpy(aux,str1);
  strcat(aux,str2);
  strcpy(*res,aux);
  free(aux);
}
```

File pointers.h

```
void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res)
```

File pointers.i

```
%module pointers
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "pointers.h"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"
%include "cpointer.i"
%include "cstring.i"

%pointer_functions(char *, charp);
extern void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res);
```

File setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension


pointers_module = Extension('_pointers',
                       sources=['pointers_wrap.cxx', 'pointers.cpp'],
                       )

setup (name = 'pointers',
   version = '0.1',
   author      = "SWIG Docs",
   description = """Simple swig example from docs""",
   ext_modules = [pointers_module],
   py_modules = ["pointers"],
   )
```

Finally, the python main:

```
import pointers

result = new_charp()
pointers.conc("Hello ","World!", result);
print(result)
delete_charp(result)
```

And all of them are compiled with terminal commands:

```
swig -c++ -python pointers.i
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But the compiler return error:

```
pointers_wrap.cxx: In function ‘char** copy_charp(char*)’:
pointers_wrap.cxx:3124:58: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to            
type ‘const char*&’ return (new char *(static_cast< const char *& >(value)));
                                                                         ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any helps?

[UPDATE TO THE QUESTION]

As suggested by @MarkTolonen I tried to change the pointers.i file in the following way:

New file pointers.i:

```
%module pointers

%{
#include "pointers.h"
%}

// This input typemap declares that char** requires no input parameter.
// Instead, the address of a local char* is used to call the function.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) char** (char* tmp) %{
  $1 = &tmp;
%}

// After the function is called, the char** parameter contains a malloc'ed char* pointer.
// Construct a Python Unicode object (I'm using Python 3) and append it to
// any existing return value for the wrapper.
%typemap(argout) char** %{
  PyObject *obj = PyUnicode_FromString(*$1);
  $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,obj);
%}

// The malloc'ed pointer is no longer needed, so make sure it is freed.
%typemap(freearg) char** %{
  free(*$1);
%}

// Now that the typemap exists, let swig wrap the header.
%include "pointers.h"
```

Compiling with:

```
swig -c++ -python pointers.i
g++ --std=c++11 -fPIC -c pointers.cpp
g++ --std=c++11 -fPIC -c pointers_wrap.cxx -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m
```

And then I got the error:

```
In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_conc(PyObject*, PyObject*):`
pointers_wrap.cxx:3618:1: error: jump to label ‘fail’ [-fpermissive]
fail:
pointers_wrap.cxx:1222:49: note:   from here
 #define SWIG_fail                  goto fail

pointers_wrap.cxx:2999:68: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_fail’
 #define SWIG_exception_fail(code, msg) do { SWIG_Error(code, msg); SWIG_fail; } while(0)
pointers_wrap.cxx:3603:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_exception_fail’
 SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res2), "in method '" "conc" "', argument " "2"" of type '" "char *""'");

pointers_wrap.cxx:3609:8: note:   crosses initialization of ‘_object* obj’
 auto obj = PyUnicode_FromString(*arg3);
pointers_wrap.cxx:3618:1: error: jump to label ‘fail’ [-fpermissive]
fail:

pointers_wrap.cxx:1222:49: note:   from here
 #define SWIG_fail                     goto fail
pointers_wrap.cxx:2999:68: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_fail’
 #define SWIG_exception_fail(code, msg) do { SWIG_Error(code, msg); SWIG_fail; } while(0)
pointers_wrap.cxx:3598:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_exception_fail’
 SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "conc" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "char *""'");

pointers_wrap.cxx:3609:8: note:   crosses initialization of ‘_object* obj’
 auto obj = PyUnicode_FromString(*arg3);

pointers_wrap.cxx:3618:1: error: jump to label ‘fail’ [-fpermissive]
fail:
pointers_wrap.cxx:1222:49: note:   from here
 #define SWIG_fail                   goto fail
pointers_wrap.cxx:3595:62: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWIG_fail’
 if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"OO:conc",&obj0,&obj1)) SWIG_fail;
pointers_wrap.cxx:3609:8: note:   crosses initialization of ‘_object* obj’
 auto obj = PyUnicode_FromString(*arg3);
```

It works on this windows OS but not on my ubuntu. Can anyone tell how to deal with it. I really don't know how resolve my pointers problem.

Comment: where is pointers_wrap.cxx coming from? >3k lines in a single file makes me dizzy even without seeing the file

Comment: yeah, it's created running the file setup.py. It's the automatic created file by swig to build the wrapper file. And it's needed in the creation of the swig module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SWIG 3.0 documentation, near the end of `§9.2.1 cpointer.i`:

> Note: None of these macros can be used to safely work with strings (char * or char **).

So you will have to resort to typemaps.  Below is an example:

**pointers.cpp**

I had to change your source slightly.  A `char**` argument should return the allocated pointer, and not free it:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pointers.h"

void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res){
  *res = (char *)malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1);
  strcpy(*res,str1);
  strcat(*res,str2);
}
```

**pointers.h**

```
void conc(char *str1, char *str2, char **res);
```

**pointers.i**

This version of the swig file declares the typemaps to handle the `char**` output argument.

```
%module pointers

%{
#include "pointers.h"
%}

// This input typemap declares that char** requires no input parameter.
// Instead, the address of a local char* is used to call the function.
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) char** (char* tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

// After the function is called, the char** parameter contains a malloc'ed char* pointer.
// Construct a Python Unicode object (I'm using Python 3) and append it to
// any existing return value for the wrapper.
%typemap(argout) char** (PyObject* obj) %{
    obj = PyUnicode_FromString(*$1);
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,obj);
%}

// The malloc'ed pointer is no longer needed, so make sure it is freed.
%typemap(freearg) char** %{
    free(*$1);
%}

// Now that the typemap exists, let swig wrap the header.
%include "pointers.h"
```

**test.py**

```
import pointers
result = pointers.conc('Hello ','World!');
print(result)
```

**Output**

> Hello World!

Comment: thank you! But compiling your code, I got some errors, all referring `jump to label 'fail'` in the function `PyObject* _wrap_conc(PyObject*, PyObject*)` and a note: `crosses initialization of '_object* obj'` on `auto obj =`. Do u know why?

Comment: @lorsp000 Your C++ compiler is old. Change auto to the return type of PyUnicodeFromString. I think it is PyObject*.

Comment: I tried to change the return type, but still doesn't work. On the other hand I got a g++ 6.3.0 version, is it too old for PyUnicodeFromString?

Comment: It's not the c++ compiler, I've just run it with command --str=c++11.

Comment: I've explained the problem better in a new answer.

Comment: @lorsp000 I made a change to `pointers.i` that might fix the problem.  Your compiler is indicating that the initialization of `obj` can be skipped.  I changed the way it was declared so SWIG will declare the variable at the top of the wrapper instead of inline.

Comment: Once again thks @MarkTolonen. Now the module compiles. But using it, in particular when the code compute `strcat(*res,str2)`, I got a `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` error. Am I calling the variable wrong? Sorry I now I'm asking u too much...but I'm really stuck

Comment: Sorry @MarkTolonen! The code works!! thank you very much.